# Imprimir un DIV manteniendo el CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, print

intento mandar a imprimir un "div" en el que aparece un "comprobante de un pedido, no consigo mantener los estilos CSS cuando me abre la ventana de imprimir.

Esta es mi función:

```
function printDiv(divVer) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divVer).innerHTML;
        var document_html = window.open("_blank");
         document_html.document.write( "<html><head><title>Imprimir Pedido</title>" );
         document_html.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/styles.css\" media=\"all\">" );
         document_html.document.write( "</head><body>" );
         document_html.document.write( printContents );
         document_html.document.write( "</body></html>" );
         setTimeout(function () {
               document_html.print();
           }, 500)
}

$(document).on('click','#imprimirPedido' ,function() {
    printDiv('divVer')
});
```

Y este el DIV a imprimir:

> ```
>           <div id="divVer" class="columna">
>               <h4 class="titulo">Detalles del Pedido</h4>
>           </div>
> ```

Se encuentra vacío, ya que se rellena desde ajax, pero el caso que pierde el css:

[image: Esto es el DIV]
[image: Est es lo que me sale al Imprimir]

- ¿Como podría arreglar esto?
  Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar un @media. Existe uno específico para gestionar los estilos que se usaran en la impresión:

**CSS**

```
@media print {
  /* Reglas CSS para impresión */
}
```

También podrías usar un hoja de estilos diferente para los estilos de impresión. Esta manera de hacerse se encuentra mayormente soportada por los navegadores:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: Okey, me coje algunos estilos! pero no consigo que la fuente me la muestre!! ¿Tal vez sea por que es de google fonts?

Comment: Puedes probar a descargarte la fuente y cargarla con un @font-face en vez de importarla directamente desde google fonts.

Comment: No hace falta descargar la fuente, copia la direccion del import de google y pegala en el navegador, te saldra el css que esta importando, y copia el font face de ahi.

Comment: Buen truquillo, no lo conocía. ¡Gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 0):

bueno al parecer hay una solución sencilla con google Crome te da una opcion que dice "GRAFICOS EN SEGUNDO PLANO" y claro al marcar esta opcion se vera tal cual la quieres .... suerte